# HOw do I pass an instance of my browser Window class from a [ClassInitialize] method to another class that is not static

Tags: c#, unit-testing, coded-ui-tests, vstest

While working on my first big program for coded ui I found out that i had messed up the way i was moving across the application.  This manifested its self in making my program really slow, i mean turtle slow lol.  I figured this out after coding most of the program and being very disappointed by the performance.

The issue is i was not passing an instance of my browser between my classes and was strictly relying i should say on my U.I maps i created(I can go into details about this if anyone wants to know). When i started out the project I knew i had to do that but since i created a   ***[ClassInitialize] to kick off browser for all of my test methods. The area that i kicked off my browser i wasn't able to pass it since it was static and this cause me to do alot of un-needed consequences in how i built the U.I maps and such.***

Currently i'm thinking that I either need to change it to a test initialize and kick off the launching of my browser in one my test methods or the other way i was thinking of is to pass the instance of my browser object by calling my first class that i use.  Here is the code below of what i currently have i'd like some opinions on the best way to go about it.

```
  [ClassInitialize]
    public static void GoToHomePage(TestContext context)
    {
        Playback.Initialize();

        MyCodedUITests.StartTest();
        //Playback.PlaybackSettings.MatchExactHierarchy = true;
       // //dev
       //VyguideWindow = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri(@"http://ThesiteIlaunch"));
        //prod
        VyguideWindow = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri(@"http://ThesiteILauch"));
        proc = VyguideWindow.Process;
        VyguideWindow.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;
        VyguideWindow.Maximized = true;
        HomePage passWnd = new HomePage();
        passWnd.PassBrows(VyguideWindow);

    }

    public BrowserWindow PassBrows(BrowserWindow window)
    { 
       BrowserWindow myBrowser  = window;

       return myBrowser;
    }
```

Please give me some feedback on best practice or if i should use test initialize. The initial thinking was that i was going to use the classinitialize and all my other test methods was going to run from it, that was the reason i first did it, but i dont know if this is still doable. Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I have a static class that I use for variables that I will have to use throughout the test.  So, I declare the browser window here:

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static BrowserWindow Browser;
}
```

And then instantiate it in my initialization.

```
[ClassInitialize]
public void ClassInitialize()
{
    Playback.Initialize();
    MyCodedUITests.StartTest();

    // dev
    //GlobalVariables.Browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri(@"http://ThesiteIlaunch"));

    // prod
    GlobalVariables.Browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri(@"http://ThesiteILauch"));


    GlobalVariables.Browser.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;
    GlobalVariables.Browser.Maximized = true;
}
```

Now, I can use the `GlobalVariables.Browser` object in my UIMaps as the parent object for all new objects.

```
public HtmlControl MyButton
{
    get
    {
        HtmlControl target = new HtmlControl(GlobalVariables.Browser);
        target.SearchProperties[propName] = "blah";
        return target;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I don't know why i didn't think of that. I'm hoping that by passing along my browser that this should greatly speed up my overall playback, doing this will also cause me to re-architect my current solution but i'd rather have it done correct. Thanks again.